# How to read sub cell data in an Excel file

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table like this. How can I read Merge Column data?

[image: table]

Comment: I solve this problem like this:

Answer (score 0):

```
public function importExcel(Request $request) {

    if ($request->hasFile('import_file')) {
        $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $excel = [];

        Excel::load($path, function($reader) use (&$excel) {
            $objExcel = $reader->getExcel();
            $sheet = $objExcel->getSheet(0);
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
            for ($row = 4; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
            $excel[] = $rowData[0];
        }
        foreach ($excel as $excel_data) {

             // $a=$excel_data[0]; // value will find like this



        }

        });
    }
}
```